# Kendo grid filter does not work with columns with special characters

Tags: kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI Grid to display data. I am generating gird with dynamic column names so, spaces, numbers and special characters(_) are possible as column field. To achieve this, I have to pass column name like `['column_1']`. This works proper for displaying data, but in this case column filter is not working specific for date columns. Below is example code.

```
  {
    field: "['Column_1']",
    title: "Column 1",
    format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt}",
    filterable: {
      ui: "datetimepicker"
    }
  }
```

This will display grid header and data proper but at the time of filtering date column, it gives below error.

```
getTime is not a function
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the relevant code, so we understand your situation?

Comment: Thanks for taking interest in this issue Andrej. I have added relevant code. Please check and let me know if you have any idea.